# CloudFront misses even with expiry set to a year

Tags: magento, nginx, amazon-cloudfront

I have a magento application (www(dot)raptorsupplies(dot)com) running on nginx with images being served from CloudFront. In my CloudFront behaviour I am using **Use Origin Cache Headers**. While in my magento.conf I have the following configuration

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 365d; ## Assume all files are cachable
        log_not_found off;
        add_header  Cache-Control public;
}
```

but still when I access the home page I randomly get a lot of cloudfront misses. The response header however does contain expiry date of a year ahead.[image]

Any help on why its happening is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing 'Hit from cloudfront' consistently for that resource.

If you've just set-up the distribution, it may be that you're accessing it with different CloudFront nodes, that hadn't cached the resource yet.

Comment: The behavior is random, one day I see hits and the next day the first time I access it I sometime get a miss. And I am accessing it from the same location so shouldn't it be serving from the same node?
And talking about the same resource, in CloudFront stats I see 68.26% hit ratio which I think is quite low.

Comment: AWS don’t guarantee to hold all objects in the cache:

If an object in an edge location isn't frequently requested, CloudFront might evict the object—remove the object before its expiration date—to make room for objects that have been requested more recently.

Perhaps you’re seeing this behaviour for most of your objects - in which case, the popularity argument might not be applicable. It might be worth posting on the CloudFront forum (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=46&start=0) and see if anyone from AWS can give you an answer.